# How can I combine pieces of pdf file using QPrinter and print on A4 paper?

Tags: qprinter

I want to combine 3 different pdf files with ECG wave forms and print on one A4 paper.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem using pdftk and QProcess in Linux.

```
    QProcess shellProc;
    QString cpCommand;
    QStringList cpArgs;
    cpCommand="pdfunite";
    cpArgs<<"/home/pmon/Desktop/spectrogramECGI.pdf"; 
    cpArgs<<"/home/pmon/Desktop/spectrogramECGII.pdf";
    cpArgs<<"/home/pmon/Desktop/spectrogramECGIII.pdf";
    cpArgs<<"/home/pmon/Desktop/spectrogramOUTPUT.pdf"; //Combined Pdf
    shellProc.start(cpCommand,cpArgs);
    shellProc.waitForFinished();
```

[link for pdftk](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-merge-pdf-files-in-command-line-on-linux/)